# How to share state between Rekit features?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using [Rekit](https://rekit.js.org/), and totally love it, it has made the task of learning React and Redux so much easier, but its slightly opinionated view on how to structure things leaves me wondering what is the best practice to share state between 2 different features of an app (e.g. the logged in user, and maybe some other data).

I could go to localStorage but that seems counter intuitive to the idea of Redux being a "source of truth".

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please review my answer and tell me if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Rekit question, your question is actually a Redux question.

Features components are Redux connected components, meaning at the very bottom of the component file, you'll find something like this :

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DefaultPage)
```

The first parameter of `connect` is `mapStateToProps` which is the function you want to look at as it allows you to access the entire Redux store, and fetch some values, which will be passed as a component's property (`this.props`).

Rekit adds this method in your components for you, but it *only* imports the component's store data by default.
You need to add the other features state you want to access to.

For example, I have a `LoginPage` component in a `Users` feature. The `LoginPage` component's `mapStateToProps` function is like that :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    users: state.users,
  }
}
```

As you can see, the function gets the global Redux `state` object passed as a parameter, and the function fetches the `state.users` and assign it as a prop named `users` (this function's returned values are translated as `props` as its name state it).

*FYI: The state's `users` is defined in the `Others/common/rootReducer.js` file so that Redux is aware of it.*

Now, given you have a `Config` Rekit feature so that the `state.config` would contains all the definef states from that feature.
In order to access its state, you would have to add `config: state.config` and then the config states would be available in the component's `this.props` :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    config: state.config,
    users: state.users,
  }
}
```

For instance, let's say, the `Config` feature has defined a `signUpOpen` state key to `true` and you'd like to check it from the `LoginPage` component if the sign ups are open.

With that code, in the `LoginPage` component `render()` I can access `this.props.signUpOpen`.

If you need more info, please check [the Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics).